# In WolframAlpha, how can I make a Scatter Plot without connecting points?

Tags: plotting, wolfram-alpha-queries

How do I plot a list of points without connecting the dots in `WolframAlpha`?

I tried, for example, `ListPlot[{{1,2},{5,3},{6,5}}]`, but that still resulted in a plot that connected the dots. How can I create a graph with no connecting lines?

Thanks,

A

Comment: `ListPlot[{{1,2},{5,3},{6,5}}, Joined->False]` also doesn't work.

Comment: `Disk[{1,2}] and Disk[{5,3}] and Disk[{6,5}]` gives large "dots."  `Circle[...]...` and `(1,2) and (5,3) and (6,5)` also work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because WolframAlpha queries are mentioned in the forum's charter as being off-topic unless they involve calls from within Mathematica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

According to @xzczd in my comment: Simply removing the outermost braces will work, i.e. `{0,0},{1,2},{5,3},{6,5}`.

**Original Answer**

`(0,0) (1,2) (5,3) (6,5)` worked.

To efficiently convert your lists to this form:

```
convertlist[expr_] := 
StringReplace["(0,0) " <> ToString[expr], {"{{" -> "(", "}}" -> ")", "}, {" -> ") ("}]
```

[image]

Comparing to the desired result in Mathematica:
[image]

Note that I added a point `(0,0)`. This is because Wolfram|Alpha automatically makes the left bottom point on the coordinates (or be the origin), causing the point hard to find without a connection line between them. You can change this point to any other one you like.

This is the result without adding the additional point.

[image]

This is the result with your input.

[image]

Comment: Seems that parentheses aren't necessary: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%7D%2C%7B5%2C3%7D%2C%7B6%2C5%7D

Comment: @xzczd 我明白了，谢谢！